# Ajax + php not working, php is working but javascript not

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

PHP code works, but javascript does not work. And I can't understand what's wrong with him. How to make it work? Link https://nice-host.com/domain

Javascript code

```
             $("#src-btn").click(function() { 
                
                var domainname = $('#domain-name').val();
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "domain-search.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: 'Domain '+domainname,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        output = '<div class="success">'+data.text+'</div>';
        
                        $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();           
                    }
                });
            });
            
            $("#domain-search input").keyup(function() { 
                $("#domain-search input").css('border-color',''); 
                $("#result").slideUp();
            });
```

```
        $domainname = $_POST["domain-name"];
        if (isset($_POST["domain-name"])) {
            if ( gethostbyname($domainname) != $domainname ) {
                echo "<script>alert('Found')</script>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<script>alert('Not found')</script>";
            }
        } else {
            $output = json_encode(array('type' => 'error', 'text' => 'Empty'));
            die($output);
        }
```

HTML code

```
                    <div id="result"></div>
                    <form class="domain-search-form parsley-validate" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".5" method="post" id="domain-search" name="domain-search">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Domain name" id="domain-name" name="domain-name" required>
                        <button class="src-btn" name="src-btn" id="src-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Please, explain what is not working, and if possible add the error message.

Comment: If you send the form via action directly to the php file everything works, but via JavaScript does not show any result (only the page is reloaded and nothing more). The console does not show any error

Comment: check the network tab in your browser and look what you php is returning

Comment: whats is this link https://nice-host.com/domain ?

Comment: Link to website

Comment: found or not found, if i send via 'action' to the php file

Comment: returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your request did not send the correct data, `domain-name` is the parameter name you need to send.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "domain-search.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: {'domain-name':domainname},
    success: function(data)
    {
        output = '<div class="success">'+data.text+'</div>';

        $("#result").hide().html(output).slideDown();           
    }
});
```